# fann_create_from_file() undefined function on Ubuntu 16

Tags: php, apt-get, fann

I installed php fann (https://github.com/bukka/php-fann) in a Ubuntu 16 Server, here is the console output:

```
sudo apt-get install libfann-*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libfann-dbg' for glob 'libfann-*'
Note, selecting 'libfann-dev' for glob 'libfann-*'
Note, selecting 'libfann-doc' for glob 'libfann-*'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfann-dbg libfann-dev libfann-doc
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,860 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libfann-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 86590 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfann-dev_2.2.0+ds-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfann-dev:amd64 (2.2.0+ds-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfann-doc.
Preparing to unpack .../libfann-doc_2.2.0+ds-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libfann-doc (2.2.0+ds-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfann-dbg:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfann-dbg_2.2.0+ds-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfann-dbg:amd64 (2.2.0+ds-2) ...
Setting up libfann-dev:amd64 (2.2.0+ds-2) ...
Setting up libfann-doc (2.2.0+ds-2) ...
Setting up libfann-dbg:amd64 (2.2.0+ds-2) ...
```

It seems there aren't errors, but when I try to call fann_create_from_file() I get:

```
Call to undefined function fann_create_from_file() in /var/www/html/../somefile.php on line XX
```

What can be wrong? I'm working with PHP 5.6, may apt-get configuring lib fann for an older (or another) php installation?

**Update 1**

I also tried **sudo apt-get install libfann-dev**

**Update 2**

Same issue on **Ubuntu 14**

```
sudo apt-get install libfann-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libfann-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfann-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 199 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/176 kB of archives.
After this operation, 703 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libfann-dev.
(Reading database ... 56278 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfann-dev_2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfann-dev (2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libfann-dev (2.1.0~beta~dfsg-8ubuntu1) ...
```

Running:

```
Call to undefined function fann_create_from_file
```

**Update 3**

I compiled the "fann.so" library running:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/bukka/php-fann.git
cd php-fann
phpize
./configure --with-fann
make
sudo make install
```

The build process runned successfully so I added "fann.so" to my PHP.ini and I got:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/fann.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/fann.so: undefined symbol: zend_list_close in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to make it work:

1. sudo apt-get install libfann-dev
2. sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev
3. sudo apt-get install php-pear
4. sudo pecl install fann (this will build the correct version of "fann.so" and put it in a php acessible folder)
5. add the follow line to PHP.ini "extension=fann.so;"